# ASP.NET Executing JavaScript Confirm alert message in C# code behind only if condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a confirmation window that will add a new value to database if the user clicks OK in the popup window. Also i have to verify a specific criteria before that. I have button and text box and the text box contains a required field validator. So if i click the button this validator fires first.

I will enter a number in this text box and press add, it will fetch a name value corresponding to this number from database and if name is found then it should ask a confirmation "Do you want to add this name?" and if name is not found then it should just popup a alert saying "name not found". If number value is less than 6 then it will show another popup saying "number not valid". I have done this as given below.

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_add" runat="server" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="required_add_" ControlToValidate="text_add" ErrorMessage="Required" runat="server">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="button_add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClientClick="Confirm()" OnClick="button_add_Click" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Do you confirm?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**C#**

```
protected void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (text_add.Text.Length < 6)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Number not valid!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        //fetch name from DB
        if (//name found)
        {
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                //add the name
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Name not found!')", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here what happens is whenever i enter a number into text box and click the button, the Confirm() function is executed at first even if the number is less than 6 digits and in case i enter 6 digits and the name is not found in database  same way the Confirm() function is executed. If i enter number less than 6 digits the confirm box comes first and after that the alert saying "number not valid" comes. How can i fire the confirm() function only if the conditions are met. I want to fire the confirm() function only if the button press event goes into the `if (//name found)` condition.

**EDIT**

I have removed the `OnClientClick` from the button and then changed the C# code to the following

```
protected void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (text_add.Text.Length < 6)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Number not valid!')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        //fetch name from DB
        if (//name found)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "confirm", "Confirm();", true);
            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                this.AddData(sender, e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Name not found!')", true);
        }
    }
}

protected void AddData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add data
}
```

I have made a seperte function to add data. I have added the ScriptManager to open confirm box and removed the OnClientClick in button. Now when i press the button the confirm box opens only if all conditions are satisfied. But when i press OK in confirm box nothing happens. The AddData function is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your confirm function to this:

```
function Confirm() {
    if (Page_ClientValidate() && 
  document.getElementById('text_add').value.length >5) {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you confirm?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
   else return false;
}
```

And change The

```
onClientClick=Confirm();
```

to this:

```
onClientClick= return Confirm()
```

to avoid submit under 6 length text.

Comment: But i still have to satisfy one more condition, i have to use the entered number and check if it is available in database, only if it is available the confirm box should appear. I have done something but it is still half way there. let me add the edit in question

Comment: Why you don't use ajax for this? ajax is very good for this approaches.

Comment: I am still new to ASP.NET and not aware of lot of things..I am still learning. Is it possible to call the AddData function in the javascript Confirm() method under Yes condition?

Comment: should i also add `onClientClick= return Confirm()` to the button?

Comment: Why you except your confirm button submit the page? In first approach your confirm appear after submit button (button_add) click and after confirm page goes to submit. But in new way after page come back to confirmation you have not any submition function related to your confirmation.

Comment: Instead of confirm you create a div that have buttons 'No' and 'Yes' and the yes button has OnClick = "button_add_Click" to fire the save event.

Comment: Yes i will keep that as my final option.. will keep trying this for a while

Answer (score 0):

You must have a hidden field between your post backs that shows it is in first post back or after confirmation:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="isReadyForSave" runat="server" Value="false"/>
```

And change your code:

```
protected void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(isReadyForSave.Value == "true" && Request.Form["confirm_value"] == "yes")
 {
  AddData();
  isReadyForSave.Value = "false";
  return;
 }
if (text_add.Text.Length < 6)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Number not valid!')", true);
}
else
{
    //fetch name from DB
    if (//name found)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "confirm", "Confirm();", true);


            isReadyForSave.Value = "true";

    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Name not found!')", true);
    }
}
}
```

And change you javascript confirm() function to this:

```
function Confirm() {
if (Page_ClientValidate() && 
 document.getElementById('text_add').value.length >5) {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm("Do you confirm?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok i will check it now and tell you

Comment: still the same..when i click OK from confirm box nothing happens

Comment: It means the page does not submit?

Comment: nothing happens actually..no error..when i click OK the confirm box disappears and nothing happens..the code inside AddData is not running

Comment: does button_add_Click fire? Did you test in debug mode?

Comment: yes the button event is fired but only the confirm part not working

Comment: @ManoPrathibhanC can you add `console.log(confirm_value.value)` before `document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);` and see what the value it is?